# Unique coroutine scope for each item collected in a flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is it possible to create a flow operator similar to collect with its own coroutine scope for each item it receives?

Lets say I have an updating list of bicycles, a `Flow<List<Bicycle>>`. For each bicycle I can request a price, unfortunately this API requires me to request the price for a single bicycle at a time. This is all fine I can spin up some requests using a couple of async builders, no problem so far. The API for requesting prices might be slow at times, potentially slower than the stream of new bicycles that becomes available or taken. This creates the issue of still working or waiting on fetching prices for bikes that are no longer available or taken. Is there any way to create a coroutine scope for each item collected from my `Flow<List<Bicycle>>` and then cancel it when a new item is collected, so that my current requests are only for the last emitted item (or bicycle) from the flow? If I understand correctly due to the sequential nature of flows, the next item is not requested until the previous is finished/completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a request only for the latest collected item then you can use `collectLatest` terminal operator. As soon as it collects a new item, the current request will be cancelled.

The `collectLatest` official documentation states:

> Terminal flow operator that collects the given flow with a provided
> action. The crucial difference from collect is that when the original
> flow emits a new value, action block for previous value is cancelled.

Here's the example exposed in the official documentation:

```
flow {
    emit(1)
    delay(50)
    emit(2)
}.collectLatest { value ->
    println("Collecting $value")
    delay(100) // Emulate work
    println("$value collected")
}
```

And it prints:

```
Collecting 1
Collecting 2
2 collected
```

You can find `collectLatest` official documentation [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect-latest.html).